# Multiple condition and expression with a ternary in php

Tags: php, conditional-operator

```
if(!$customLength){
?>
<th class="sku-label-value download-url-construct <?=$columnClassParent ?>">
 <span 
    data-option-id="<?=$values['option_id']?>"
    id="ns_code_<?= ((stripos($title, 'i.p. rating') !== false) ? 'iprating' : $title) ?>"
    data-code-sku="<?=$dataCodeSku ?>">
<?=$values['sku'] ?></span>
</th>
<?php
}
```

I want to have another ternary condition on the ID is that possible?

So for this line

```
    id="ns_code_<?= ((stripos($title, 'i.p. rating') !== false) ? 'iprating' : $title) ?>"
```

I would want to be able to account for another word also and still account for the ip rating. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You could add a ternary around the ternary. But I would suggest ditching the ternary all together if it's not a clear true/false test. Ternaries might look like a good option right now, but for many others viewing your code, including yourself in a while, they are notorious for making code less readable.
So while it might save a line or 2 right now, you might be better off avoiding ternaries and using other control structures

Comment: _"I would want to be able to account for another word also and still account for the ip rating."_ - so what does that mean, exactly? Do you want to output a _different_ word then, do you want to output both ...?

Comment: @CBroe I want it to do the first word " ip rating" and also do another for another word example " dollar amount". So I want it to do both at the same time.

Comment: Doesn't make too much sense to try and stick that much logic into a place like this, IMHO. I would create a variable beforehand. `$displayTitle = stripos($title, 'i.p. rating') !== false) ? 'iprating ' : ''; $displayTitle .= stripos($title, 'dollar amount') !== false) ? 'dollar amount' : ''; $displayTitle = $displayTitle ? $displayTitle : $title;` - put that right after the if condition, and then output the content of that variable later on.

Comment: By leaving a space behind `'iprating '`, the next step can then _append_ `dollar amount`, without the two words sticking together. (If _just_ `iprating ` gets output, that should not matter - HTML ignores leading/trailing whitespace. If it does matter for some reason, you can still `trim`the value before you output it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to account for another word instead of 'i.p. rating' in the title, you can have another ternary in the "else" part:

```php
    id="ns_code_<?= ((stripos($title, 'i.p. rating') !== false) ? 'iprating' : ((stripos($title, 'whatever') !== false) ? 'whatever' : $title)) ?>"
```

At this point, I would suggest switching back to a standard condition block for a better readability.